# add HTML tags to a string before it is displayed using TypeIt JS

Tags: javascript

I would like to add **HTML tags** and **classes** to a string before it is displayed on the page.
The library allows the use of **Callback Methods**, like `beforeString` and `afterString` however I am finding it complicated to implement this function. I have tried several methods but can't find a solution.

I'm using a simple library called [**TypeIT**](https://www.typeitjs.com/docs/vanilla/usage/)

I leave here the **Javascript** code but i add to a [**link to JsFiddle to test it**](https://jsfiddle.net/Siruts/1e4umtc9/177/).

```
// Expected output result (html tag showed)
//----------------------------------------------
// <span class="">String 1</span>         // already deleted "active" class afterString
// <span class="">String 2</span>
// <span class="active">String 3</span>   // current string added "active" class, beforeString
// and so on

// Variables
//------------------
let counter = 0

// Initialization TypeIt
//------------------
const instance = new TypeIt("#element", {
    strings: [
    'String 1',
    //'String 2',
    '<span class="active">String 2</span>',
    'String 3',
    'String 4',
    'String 5',
    //'String 6',
    '<span class="past">String 6</span>',
    'String 7',
    'String 8',
    'String 9',
    ],
    speed: 150,              // Speed text 
  breakLines: true,          // Break the lines
  html: true,                // Use Html Tags
  
  // Callback Methods
  //------------------
  beforeString: async (TypeIt) => {
    ++counter;
    console.log('Start ' + counter + ' string.');
    // Here should be added: <span class="active">.....</span>
  },
  afterString: async (TypeIt) => {
    console.log('End '+ counter + ' string.');
    console.log('-----------------------')
    // Here should be replaced: "active" with "past" class.
  },
});

instance.go();
```